# Scale down offsets for mobile/tablet views

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

My web app stores div position via its offset. The problem is that if the app is used on a desktop, the document size is too big, so a left offset of 1000px won't show on an ipad. What's the best way to scale down this offset number for optimal viewing on both tablets and desktops?

Comment: We need code, please show us what you have tried and check out http://stackoverflow.com/help for more info on how to format your question.

Comment: Downvoted. Not Constructive. It's a general question.

Answer (score 0):

Add this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

And use this:

```
body{
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 1000px; /* or any value you want */
}
```